# Magento 2 cash on delivery for particular state

Tags: magento2

I need to enable **cash on delivery** option only for a **particular state** in a country.

I have tried to do it in "**Payment methods**" from magento dashboard and found only country-wise cash on delivery option.

Kindly some one guide me to achieve this without much of coding as I am not so good in magento 2.

Comment: Any solutions please?

Answer (score 0):

First Override **Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery.php** file
using custom module and then put below code in file

```
public function isAvailable(\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null)
    {
   ...........Write your own logic here and reture true/false on basis of ................     
    return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Nilesh for your quick response. But i am not so sure how to override the mentioned file using a custom module. Can you guide me???

Comment: using di.xml you can do this

Answer (score 0):

Plugin is a best way to override or change functionality of a function with out modify its class.

So you must create a module and plugin inside it.

- To create a module please follow this link: [here](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/)
- Follow: [this link to add plugin into your module](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-plugin-interceptor.html)

You must define plugin for class `Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery` and Inside plugin class write following:

it will attach you method after isAavailable()   method.

```
public function afterIsAvailable(\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote, $result) {
    $billingaddr =$quote->getBillingAddress();
    if($billingaddr->getRegionId()!="yourvalue") {
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result; // if condition not match will return default result
}
```

Comment: Thank you Kumar for your quick response. I am not a techie guy to create the plugin. May be i would be if you can guide me how to create one. Please help.

Comment: I have updated my answer please check